# Dynamic dispatch in C++ - better syntax

Tags: c++, dynamic, lambda, c++14

I want to have a dynamic_call functionality in C++. It should trigger overload resolution and call the most specific function on the target class (Visitor) depending on the dynamic type of the argument. It should replace the visitor pattern and should work like the dynamic keyword in C#.
I pasted what I got so far below. I want to not have to declare the generic lambda on caller side but on the implementation of dynamic call to make it easier to use. Is this possible?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base { virtual ~Base() = default; };
class A : public Base {};
class B : public Base {};

template <class... Ts>
class dynamic_call {
public:
    template <class F, class Arg>
    static void call(F& func, Arg& a) {
        call_impl<F, Arg, Ts...>(func, a);
    }
private:
    template <class F, class Arg>
    static void call_impl(F& /*func*/, Arg& /*a*/) {
        //end of recursion => nothing more to be done
    }
    template <class F, class Arg, class T, class... R>
    static void call_impl(F& func, Arg& a) {
        T* t = dynamic_cast<T*>(&a);
        if(t) {
            func(*t);
        }
        call_impl<F, Arg, R...>(func, a);
    }
};

using namespace std;
struct Visitor {
    void Visit(A&) { cout << "visited for a" << endl; }
    void Visit(B&) { cout << "visited for b" << endl; }
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])
{
    Visitor v;
    auto func = [&v](auto& a) { v.Visit(a); };

    A a;
    dynamic_call<A, B>::call(func, a);

    B b;
    dynamic_call<A, B>::call(func, b);

    {
        Base& base(a);
        dynamic_call<A, B>::call(func, base);
    }
    {
        Base& base(b);
        dynamic_call<A, B>::call(func, base);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to call it like this without the need to add the generic lambda.

```
dynamic_call<A,B>::call(v, a);
```

Comment: Use `std::function` may be.Your question is unclear

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you basically want `Visit` (or a wrapped call to it) to behave like a virtual member function of `Base`? Concerning your last requirement: Change `Visit` to `operator()` in `Visitor` and your line will work.

Comment: @eichhörnchen nope i want to call the correct Implementation of visit depending on the runtime Type of the Argument. This is not a normal virtual call.

Comment: A virtual call selects the overwritten method based on the runtime type of `this`, i.e. if `Visit` was a virtual method in `Base` and overwritten in `A` and `B` without parameters, then `a.Visit()`, `b.Visit()` and `base.Visit()` would behave exactly like your dynamic_call examples.

Comment: @eichhörnchen you are right but I want to have the visit function to be on the Visitor instead. This Just like the Visitor Pattern or Double dispatch. 
To clarify - I want to make a "virtual" call depending on  a argument not on this.

Comment: Are replacing `Visit` by `operator()`, replacing `func(*t)` by `func.Visit(*t)`, doing the dispatch inside `Visit` or wrapping the dispatching call in an additional member function / struct no options?

Comment: @eichhörnchen I don't quite get what you are suggesting. Could you make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas, I am not sure what your requirements are, so they might not fit:

1. Change `Visit` into `operator()`. Then the call syntax reduces to `dynamic_call<A,B>::call(v, a);` as you required. Of course that is only possible if the interface of the visitor may be changed.
2. Change `func(*t)` in `call_impl` to `func.Visit(*t)`. Then again the caller can use `dynamic_call<A,B>::call(v, a);` and no change to the interface of the visitor is necessary. However every visitor used with `dynamic_call` now needs to define `Visit` as visitor method. I think `operator()` is cleaner and follows the usual patterns, e.g. for Predicates in the standard library more.

I don't particularly like either of these because the caller always has to know the possible overloads available in the visitor and has to remember using `dynamic_call`. So I propose to solve everything in the visitor struct:

3. ```
   struct Visitor {
       void Visit(A&) {
           cout << "visited for a" << endl;
       }
       void Visit(B&) {
           cout << "visited for b" << endl;
       }
       void Visit(Base& x) {
           dynamic_call<A,B>::call([this](auto& x){Visit(x);}, x);
       }
   };
   ```

   This can be called with `v.Visit(a)`, `v.Visit(b)` and `v.Visit(base)`. This way the user of `Visitor` does not need to know anything about the varying behavior for different derived classes.
4. If you do not want to modify `Visitor`, then you can just add the overload via inheritance:

   ```
   struct DynamicVisitor : Visitor {
       void Visit(Base& x) {
           dynamic_call<A,B>::call([this](auto& x){Visit(x);}, x);
       }
   };
   ```

The points can be combined, for example into:

```
struct Visitor {
    void operator()(A&) {
        cout << "visited for a" << endl;
    }
    void operator()(B&) {
        cout << "visited for b" << endl;
    }
    void operator()(Base& x) {
        dynamic_call<A,B>::call(*this, x);
    }
};
```

Used as `v(a)`, `v(b)` and `v(base)`.

Comment: This is definitely interesting

Comment: Took me some time to figure out how this works but this is what I was searching